# Shattering a bottle with bullet

Tags: physics

what would the best and easiest way be to shatter three bottles. I tried cell fracture but the vertices just mix and create this weird vertices blob.

I am trying to shatter it with a bullet but if I can't create the shatter portion I am not sure how I will complete this model. Any links would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Fracture modifier is the way to go. You need the extra vertices to define the mesh. You really should watch a tutorial on this, as I think this is way outside the scope of this site. If you have a specific issue, feel free to post it though.

Comment: Thank you for the response I will go ahead and try that.

Comment: An alternative would be using the explode modifier. It will not be as accurate as the fracture modifier but with some tweaking it might give you the results you are after.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ your solution was right on target thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with the model after appending to a different project a couple of times and it occurred to me how silly I was being.  I had it set to be visible on frame 1 but on frame 50 it became invisible then on frame 51 I had set it back to become visible on accident. :P I am a silly rabbit sometimes.